# My game runs infinitely

Tags: java, loops

I have an assignment to create a [game of Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim).

I have created two classes, one for the game:

```
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Surge
 */
public class Nim implements InteractiveGame
{

    private int pilesize;
    private boolean playSmart;  //true iff the computer plays smart
        private boolean playersTurn;    //true iff it is the human player’s turn to move
        private String gameRecord;  //Complete history of the game’s progression

    public Nim(boolean playSmart, boolean playerFirst)
        {
           this.playSmart = playSmart;
           this.playersTurn = playerFirst;
           pilesize = (int)((Math.random() * 91) + 10);
           this.gameRecord = " Marble Game";
        }

 @Override
    public boolean isCompleted()
    {
        return pilesize == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValidMove(String move) 
    {

      try
      {  //Interpret move as an integer, check if in range
           int number = Integer.parseInt(move);
         return number >= 1  && number <= pilesize / 2 ;
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException nfex)
      {  //The move could not be parsed as an integer
         return false;
      }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlayersTurn()
    {
        return this.playersTurn;
    }

    @Override
    public void makePlayersMove(String move) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int marbles_to_remove = input.nextInt(); 
        this.gameRecord = "How many marbles do you want to remove:";

        while ((marbles_to_remove != 1) && (marbles_to_remove <= 0 || marbles_to_remove > pilesize / 2))
                playersTurn = false;


        pilesize -= marbles_to_remove;
    }



    @Override
    public void makeComputersMove() {
         while (pilesize > 0) 
          {
        System.out.println("Current number of marlbes in pile: " +  pilesize);
        int marbles_to_remove = 0;
        if (!playersTurn) {
        if (playSmart || (pilesize == 1 || pilesize == 3
                    || pilesize== 7 || pilesize == 15 || pilesize == 31
                    || pilesize == 63)) {
            marbles_to_remove = (int) (Math.random() * (pilesize / 2 + 1)) + 1;
        }
        else {
            if (pilesize > 63) {
            marbles_to_remove = pilesize - 63;
            }
            else if (pilesize > 31) {
            marbles_to_remove = pilesize - 31;
            }
            else if (pilesize > 15) {
            marbles_to_remove = pilesize - 15;
            }
            else if (pilesize > 7) {
            marbles_to_remove = pilesize - 7;
            }
            else if (pilesize > 3) {
            marbles_to_remove = pilesize - 3;
            }
            else {
            marbles_to_remove = pilesize - 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Computer removes " + marbles_to_remove  + " marble" + ((marbles_to_remove > 1)? "s": ""));
        playersTurn = true;
        }

    }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean playerHasWon() 
    {
        boolean win = false;
        if(pilesize == 1 && !playersTurn)
            win = true;
        return win;
    }

    @Override
    public String movePrompt() 
    {
        return this.gameRecord + "\nGuess a number";
    }



}
```

and another for the client:

```
public class InteractiveGamePlayer
{
    //Play a series of two-person Interactive Games 
    //  between a HUMAN player and the COMPUTER Player
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        InteractiveGame game;
        do
        {
            game = promptForGame(); 

            if (game != null)
                play( game );

        } while ( game != null );
    }

    //Prompt the HUMAN Player for the name of the game and its parameters:
    //     1) COMPUTER plays smart      2) HUMAN plays first
   //Returns a new instance of the selected game, null if the HUMAN quits
    private static InteractiveGame  promptForGame()
    {
        Object[] gameOptions = {"GUESS", "NIM"};
        String gameName = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                         "Choose a game, or CANCEL", "GAME MENU",
                                                   JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,
                                                   gameOptions, gameOptions[0] );
      if ( gameName != null )
      {  //Allow the Human Player to select the game options
         boolean smartMode = gameOption("Computer plays SMART?") ;
         boolean playFirst = gameOption("Will YOU play FIRST?") ;
         switch ( gameName )  //Return the selected game
         {
            case "GUESS"   : return new GuessingGame(smartMode, playFirst );
            case "NIM"     : return new Nim(smartMode, playFirst);
         }
      }
      return null;
    }

   //The HUMAN Palyer selects a game option
   private static boolean gameOption(String prompt)
   {
      return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, prompt) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
   }

    //Play a selected 2-person game by alternating turns
    //  between the HUMAN Player and the COMPUTER Player
    private static void play(InteractiveGame game)
    {
        while ( !game.isCompleted() )
            if ( game.isPlayersTurn() )
                game.makePlayersMove( promptForMove(game) );
            else
                game.makeComputersMove();

        String message = game + "\n\n" + 
                      (game.playerHasWon() ?  "Well Done!" : "Hard Luck!") ;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);   
    }

    //Prompt the HUMAN Player to enter their next move
    // The prompt is repeated until a legal move is entered
    private static String promptForMove(InteractiveGame game)
    {
      String prompt = game.movePrompt() + " ?";
        do
        {
            String playersMove = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, prompt );

            if ( game.isValidMove( playersMove ) )
            return playersMove;

         prompt += "\n" + playersMove + " is INVALID";  

        } while ( true );
    }   
}
```

But when I run my program, I get no output no matter what input I give it. The program just runs infinitely with blank output. What am I doing wrong?
also the movePrompt method has these specifications
The prompt for a player’s move must include a clear representation of the current state of the game; the prompt must show sufficient information to allow the player to decide on their next move. Assume that the human player is unfamiliar with Nim. The prompts must be implemented using JOptionPane methods.

Comment: Are you able to use a debugger to step through your program as it runs? This would normally help the cause of your problem, eg. an infinite loop, pretty quickly.

Comment: i haven't but thanks for the advice

Comment: As @dave commented, a debugger is a very handy tool in cases like these. In fact learning to use a debugger will save you a lot of effort in the long run to help debug your own programs.

Answer (score 0):

At least this construct in `makePlayersMove(...)` method easily creates an infinite loop:

```
while ((marbles_to_remove != 1) && (marbles_to_remove <= 0 || marbles_to_remove > pilesize / 2))
    playersTurn = false;
```

Since the value of `marbles_to_remove` never changes inside the loop, if the loop condition is met once, it will be met an infinite times more.

You should extend the loop to keep asking the user for a new input (now it's only asked once outside the loop), until the input is within the defined parameters.

---

Also the while loop in `makeComputersMove(...)` becomes an infinite loop, because your loop condition is `while (pilesize > 0)` and `pilesize` doesn't change inside the loop. So, if it's above zero when entering the loop, it will remain above zero for an eternity. If you only want the computer to make  one move at a time, don't see why you need the loop at all.

Comment: i tried commenting out the while loop in makePlayersMove and it still gives infinte loop with output from makeComputerMove

Comment: Basically same issue there. You need to be careful with `while` and `do ... while` loops, they easily create infinite loops.